# Using ArgumentParser to run a class function

Tags: python

So I am adding configurability to run my Data Ingest from command line, specifically using ArgParser.

I want to pass the variables:

self, region, tv_type, dest_bucket, source_bucket, aws_profile, database, table, and region to my `IngestClass` but I am getting

`ERROR - 'str' object has no attribute 's3c'`

So I am clearly passing a string and not a variable to the class.

Here is my `IngestClass` initialisation:

```
class IngestClass:
    """

    This class will Ingest match data for a given sports tv type

    """

    def __init__(self,
                 region,
                 tv_type,
                 database,
                 source_bucket,
                 destination_bucket,
                 table):
```

And here is the code which calls the `ingest()` function in the `IngestClass`

```
import logging
import configargparse as argparse
from ingest import IngestClass

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
description="""Ingests for a given TV, validates data, creates DB + table, 
            then partitions cleaned data by day and tv_type

""",
formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
add_config_file_help=False,
add_env_var_help=False,
)

parser.add_argument("-s", "--tv_type", help='tv_type for running the function', required=True, type=str),

parser.add_argument("-so", "--source_bucket", help='source_bucket for running the function', required=True, type=str),

parser.add_argument("-de", "--destination_bucket", help='destination_bucket for running the function', required=True,
                    type=str),

parser.add_argument("-p", "--aws_profile", help="AWS credentials", required=True, env_var='AWS_PROFILE', type=str),

parser.add_argument("-db", "--database", help="the database you want to use", default="ingest", type=str),

parser.add_argument("-t", "--table", help="the table you want to use", required=True, type=str),

parser.add_argument("-r", "--region", help="the region you want to use", default="us-east-1", type=str),

args = vars(parser.parse_args())
os.environ['AWS_PROFILE'] = args["aws_profile"]
IngestClass.ingest(region=args['region'], tv_type=args['tv_type'], database=args['database'],
                   source_bucket=args['source_bucket'], destination_bucket=args['destination_bucket'],
                   table=args['table'])
pass
```

Does anyone know how to pass a variable to the class `IngestClass` using `ArgumentParser`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate `IngestClass`. There is no `ingest` class method I can see from your example.

So the last line of your script should be:

```py
ingest = IngestClass(
    region=args['region'],
    tv_type=args['tv_type'],
    database=args['database'],
    source_bucket=args['source_bucket'],
    destination_bucket=args['destination_bucket'],
    table=args['table'],
)
```

`self` is automatically injected by Python as first positional argument.
Then you can use your `ingest` instance class as you want.

Be careful, all arguments parsed by `ArgumentParser` are string here.

Comment: Thanks! Silly me. I will convert from string to variable, and hopefully that will work